# Not able to signin to a WebForms using ITFoxtec

Tags: azure-active-directory, webforms, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Have tried to use ITFoxtec in my webform application but getting an error as below when I click on Login. I have registered the app in my default directory of my Azure AD.[image]

`<appSettings> <add key="Saml2:Issuer" value="urn:itfoxtec:identity:saml2:testwebapp" /> <add key="Saml2:SingleSignOnDestination" value="https://test-adfs.itfoxtec.com/adfs/ls/" /> <add key="Saml2:SingleLogoutDestination" value="https://test-adfs.itfoxtec.com/adfs/ls/" /> <add key="Saml2:SignatureAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /> <add key="Saml2:CertificateValidationMode" value="None" /></appSettings>` This I have added in the web.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need an administrator to consent/approve your application in Azure AD.

The config in the question looks like the sample config, and not the config you are using.

Comment: Yes Anders, it is the sample config. 
The problem was with the user not having the priviledge to use the Application. Just one follow up question though, could you please let me know what would be the 'SingleSignOnDestination' as well as 'SingleLogOutDestination' Url?

Comment: The best way is to read the 'SingleSignOnDestination' and 'SingleLogOutDestination' URLs from the Azure AD SAML 2.0 IdP metadata.